# IMPORTHTML not giving expected results

Tags: html, google-sheets

I am trying to pull data from a database website, but I am getting "Imported Content is Empty" error.
The formula I am using is
`=IMPORTHTML("https://tbcdb.com/?npcs=1","Table",1)`

I have tried table and list as the second argument and have tried a wide range of index values but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the content is empty.
Why ? Because the `<table>` on the site you're trying to import is being created with javascript, which runs after load, so google sheets doesn't see it.
You could ask the owner of the site if they offer other view options, like XML or RSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can recover data by capturing a list which contains all available information

```
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=listview).*/gi)
  eval('listview = '+jsonString[1].substring(1,jsonString[1].length-2))
```

for instance, to get all informations

```
let resultat = []; 
function decode(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=listview).*/gi)
  eval('listview = '+jsonString[1].substring(1,jsonString[1].length-2))
  getAllData(1,listview,'listview')
  return resultat
}
function getAllData(niv,obj,id) {
  const regex = new RegExp('[^0-9]+');
  for (let p in obj) {
    var newid = (regex.test(p)) ? id + '.' + p : id + '[' + p + ']';
    if (obj[p]!=null){
      if (typeof obj[p] != 'object' && typeof obj[p] != 'function'){
        resultat.push([niv, (newid), p, obj[p]]);
      }
      if (typeof obj[p] == 'object') {
        if (obj[p].length){
          resultat.push([niv, (newid), p + '[0-' +(obj[p].length-1)+ ']', 'tableau']);
        }else{
          //resultat.push([niv, (newid), p, 'parent']);
        }
        niv+=1;
        getAllData(niv, obj[p], newid );
        niv-=1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

to retrieve informations inside a table

```
function tblData(url){
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
  var jsonString = source.match(/(?<=listview).*/gi)
  eval('listview = '+jsonString[1].substring(1,jsonString[1].length-2))
  var tbl = []
  tbl.push(['name','minlevel','maxlevel','type','classification','id'])
  listview.data.forEach(function(e){
    //name  minlevel    maxlevel    type    classification  id
    tbl.push([e.name,e.minlevel,e.maxlevel,e.type,e.classification,e.id])
  })
  return tbl
}
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CkXFJoyarz1xWKaRxyAUwh2fulZncoJ5aYP6K2u9A2c/copy